# Use Javascript to Extract Data in Given Format

Tags: javascript, mysql, database-design

```
+-------+---------+----------+---------------+-------------+-----+
| serial| amount  | NameOfMyFriends                              |
+-------+---------+----------+---------------+-------------+-----+
|     1 | 1500.00 | FOOBAR1, FOOBAR2, FOOBAR3, FOOBAR4, FOOBAR5, |
|     2 | 2000.00 | FOOBAR1, FOOBAR3, FOOBAR4, FOOBAR5,          |
|     3 |  300.00 | FOOBAR1, FOOBAR2,                            |
|     4 |  600.00 | FOOBAR2, FOOBAR4,                            |
|     5 |  900.00 | FOOBAR4, FOOBAR5,                            |
|     6 |  800.00 | FOOBAR2, FOOBAR5,                            |
|     7 |  600.00 | FOOBAR1, FOOBAR3,                            |
+-------+---------+----------+---------------+-------------+-----+
```

I need to find  each one's share something like this:

1. FooBar1 's Share : 300 + 500 + 150 + 300 ===> 1250
2. FooBar2 's Share : 300 + 500 + 150 + 300 + 400 ===> 1650
3. FooBar3 's Share : 300 + 500 + 300 ===> 800
4. FooBar4 's Share : 300 + 500 + 300 + 450 + ===> 1550
5. FooBar5 's Share : 300 + 500 + 450 + 400 ===> 1650

Using JavaScript how can I extract data like this, without using any JavaScript Library?

Comment: Where are you getting the data from? and how does it look exactly?

Comment: Please provide the data source. Is it an array or anything else?

Comment: Why not doing it in SQL, then export your result as `CSV` or `JSON`?

Comment: These are the value i am getting from database, But Just for curiosity If i have table in HTML page something like above how i can find each one's Share (as asked in question) using JavaScript??

Answer (score 1):

I am answering this as a SQL question because it is tagged MySQL.

This is an awful data format.  You should have a separate association table, with one row per `serial` and `friend`.

But, if you have a `friends` table, then you can get what you want using MySQL:

```
select f.FriendName, sum(eachVal)
from YourTable t join
     Friends f
     on find_in_set(f.FriendName, t.NameOfMyFriends) > 0
group by f.FriendName;
```

Comment: I didn't understand Your Answer, can you describe how i can improve scheme (Normalize) given table.

Comment: @NOcode . . . I am assuming that your sample data is in a table in SQL.  You are storing a list using comma separated values in a column.  This would be better as an association table.  If you don't understand any of this, then you need to learn more about SQL.